# What happens if I try to use more cores than I have?

Tags: apache-spark

In my sparkconf, i can set the number of cores to use, i have 4 physical, 8 logical on my laptop, what does spark do if I specify a number that was not possible on the machine, like say 100 cores?

Comment: In my experiments with running spark in local mode I saw good results setting `master = "local[4*physical cores]"`. It doubled the utilisation of my CPUs from about 40% to around 80%. It is definitely worth trying to configure Spark to use 2, 4 or 8 times more threads than physical cores available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Number of cores doesn't describe physical cores but a number of running threads. It means that nothing really strange happens if the number is higher than a number of available cores.

Depending on your setup it can be actually a preferred configuration with value around twice a number of available cores being a commonly recommended setting. Obviously if number is to high your application will spend more time on switching between threads than actual processing.

Answer (score 2):

It heavily depends on your cluster manager. I assume that you're asking about `local[n]` run mode.

If so, the driver and the one and only one executor are the same JVM with `n` number of threads.

`DAGScheduler` - the Spark execution planner will use `n` threads to schedule as many tasks as you've told it should.

If you have more tasks, i.e. threads, than cores, your OS will have to deal with more threads than cores and schedule them appropriately.