# How can the Cores under the executor tab of Spark UI be higher than the actual number of cores on my laptop?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running Spark via PySpark/Jupyter notebook on a 4 core/8 logical processor laptop.

When I set master=local[16] and run a test command, noticed that the value under the cores column on the Executors tab on the Spark UI shows up as 16.

Just curious, how Spark can access 16 cores when my local laptop only has 4 physical cores/8 logical processors.

Under Event Timeline section on the Stages tab, it shows that 16 tasks are getting processed in parallel as well.

```
 sc = SparkContext(master="local[16]")
 t0 = time()
 rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2]*10000000)
 rdd1 = rdd.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
 print(time()-t0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912457/what-happens-if-i-try-to-use-more-cores-than-i-have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local[N] does not mean that your application (Workers, to be exact) runs on N CPU cores.

According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls:

local[K] => Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine).

local[*] => Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.

P.S. When you are running in local mode, the entire application (Master & Workers) runs on the same JVM.